# Spring-boot application can only be launched with spring-boot:run when forking - java -jar fails

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web application that I cannot start when using the executable jar directly.

I am using Spring Boot 1.2.0.RELEASE, Maven 3.0.5, Java 1.7.0_72.

I have a requirement to use the hp-roman8 character set - in order to handle incoming requests from some remote legacy systems. To provide the hp-roman8 charset I use net.freeutils.jcharset in version 1.5. 
The jcharset artifact is installed in my local repository

However when launching my application using java -jar the application fails to start and I get "java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: hp-roman8" as cause.

The same error occurs if I do mvn spring-boot:run unless I configure spring-boot-maven-plugin to always fork.
With `<fork>true</fork>` spring-boot:run starts the application successfully and the hp-roman8 charset is available on the classpath.

However `<fork>true</fork>` has no effect on the created jar, so I am still unable to launch my application using java -jar - and continue to get the "java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: hp-roman8".

The jcharset-1.5.jar is included correctly in the created executable jar file next to the rest of the dependencies in the path "lib/jcharset-1.5.jar" so I don't quite understand why it is not available on the classpath when launching the jar.

Have any of you seen similar behavior, or have any ideas as to what I could try out in order to troubleshoot or even resolve this problem?

update:
I have also tried changing the main-class to use the PropertiesLauncher instead (using the `<layout>ZIP</layout>` tag in the plugin configuration) - see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging. 
Afterwards I added loader.path to my application.properties. Even if I specify the absolute path to jcharset-1.5.jar I still get the UnsupportedCharsetException.
I also tried using an [exploded archive](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-exploded-archives) but still no go.

Comment: Looks like you're hitting http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4619777

Comment: @AndyWilkinson - Any suggestions for a workaround? If that bug is truly the cause I assume that I will see the same issues using either the Shade or OneJar plugins for creating fat jars.

Comment: I found a way around the problem - not the nicest solution but it works. I put the jcharset.jar in a folder next to my application.jar called libext/ and start my application like `java -Djava.ext.dirs=libext/ -jar application.jar`. The only other approach I have found to work for loading the charsets in the jcharset.jar inside my boot application is to include- and compile the source of jcharset as part of my application. But I prefer to keep the jcharset jar separate from my code. I still hope to find a better/cleaner solution though.

Comment: I had a similar problem and also got the UnsupportedCharsetException when using Spring Boot Maven plugin with jcharset. In my case I had a line in my code where I created a string and configured the charset when calling the string constructor. My problem could be solved by using the corresponding charset class directly (by creating an instance of the charset class) instead of Charset.forName().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Maven's shade plugin rather than Spring Boot's Maven plugin. The main difference is that the shade plugin takes all of your project's dependencies and packages them directly in the jar file, i.e. it doesn't use nested jars. While this has some disadvantages, it does mean that a single class loader is used to load all of your application's classes and, therefore, JCharset is available to the application class loader.

When you're using the Shade plugin, you shouldn't use Spring Boot's starter parent. You may want to import Boot's dependency management instead.

Your pom would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-sample-jcharset</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>spring-boot-sample-jcharset</name>
    <description>Spring Boot sample showing the use of JCharset in an executable jar</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Any additional dependencies, including JCharset -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>sample.jcharset.SampleJCharsetApplication</Main-Class>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Nice, I did not know that using Shade would case a single class loader to be used - thank you :)